# Phonegap Build Second App Replaces first app

Tags: mobile, build, config, phonegap, ios-app-signing

Good morning.

Ive been developing 2 different apps (HTMLs, CSS3, Javascript etc etc), I can develop one app, and install it on iOS Device (iPad), but when i try to install the second app, that is completely different to the 1st App, in both style and build, it replaces the first app.

Ive have been racking my brain for days over this.

Ive checked the config.xml file and all the app IDs are different.

```
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "uk.org.ebids-fueller"
    versionCode = "10"
    version     = "1.0.0" >
```

And then in my other Config.xml file it shows the following:

```
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "uk.org.ebids-controller"
    versionCode = "10"
    version     = "1.0.0" >
```

Even with a Third App it still replaces the previous builds:

```
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "uk.org.ebids-passengers"
    versionCode = "10"
    version     = "1.0.0" >
```

Yet the second app will completely wipe the first app and replace it with the second app.  This has never happened before, Ive been able to install multiple apps on a device and its never been a problem.

Can anybody help with this, what am i doing wrong? What am i missing? Any help is appreciated, Im not expecting people to write Code for me, im quite capable of doing that.  I just don't understand where im going wrong or whats change or am i doing something different.

I have searched this forum for other peoples issues with this, i found one, but it did not resolve the situation for me.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Basically just change the android:package attribute in your manifest, and then refactor your src/ folders to follow that same package name.

As a command above, just 3 steps:

- Remove platform `cordova platform remove android`
- Edit config.xml (main folder) find & replace widget id

```html
<widget id="com.foobar.mynewname" version="1.0.0" android-versionCode="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

...

- Add platform again `cordova platform add android`